# brew linking - installing mysql on maveriks

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

When I try to install mysql, I get this:

Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19/include/mysql
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19/include/mysql

I've ran brew update, doctor and have updated to the latest formula to no avail.
I've also inspected the formula and I don't understand where it is linking.

Why is it trying to link version 20 to 19 and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

There were a bunch of leftover links leftover from an old install. To get rid of them I did this:
`sudo ls -lR /usr/ | grep ^l|grep mysql|grep 19`

Then I went through and removed the bad ones and ran brew link mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

brew prune
brew link mysql